# How to set Image Slider

Tags: html, css, reactjs

```
var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
          <div>
              <img src="images/12.jpg" />
              <img src="images/11.jpg" />
              <img src="images/13.jpg" />
              <img src="images/14.jpg" />
          </div>
       )
    }
})
```

I need these 4 images as a slider can anyone give me the code using react or html with CSS

Comment: var Home = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
      return (
   
        <div>
    <img src="images/12.jpg" />
    <img src="images/11.jpg" />
    <img src="images/13.jpg" />
    <img src="images/14.jpg" />
     
    
   
    
    </div>

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean as "slider"? Can you provide some example?

Answer (score 1):

Use ready-made library, here example

```
https://github.com/jossmac/react-images
https://github.com/xiaolin/react-image-gallery
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
```

Answer (score 0):

First that is not the way to ask a question. [Check here how to ask good question.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

You can use some of all made React Slider Components, but if you want to do it on your own you can do something like this :

This is only to get the idea :

```js
class Test extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
     super();
      
      this.state = {
       marginLeft: 0
      }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.interval = setInterval(this.changeSlide.bind(this), 2000);
    }
    
    changeSlide(){
     let totalSlides = document.getElementById("inner").children.length - 1;
      
     let getWidth = document.getElementById("slide1").offsetWidth;   
      
      let marginLeft = this.state.marginLeft;
      
      if((totalSlides * -getWidth) >= this.state.marginLeft){
        marginLeft = 0
      }else{
        marginLeft = this.state.marginLeft - getWidth
        
      }
      
     this.setState({marginLeft})
    }
    
  render(){
     return (
       <div className="outter">
           <div id="inner" className="inner" style={{marginLeft: this.state.marginLeft}}>
             <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/12/29/16/12/eiskristalle-1938842_960_720.jpg" style={{maxWidth: "100%"}} id="slide1"/>
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/10/16/09/15/frost-490807_960_720.jpg" style={{maxWidth: "100%"}} id="slide2"/>
              <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/01/07/24/winter-654442_960_720.jpg" id="slide3"/>
              
           </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```css
.outter{
  width: 500px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner{
  width: 1000%;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.inner img{
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

In `componentDidMount` set interval to call the function to change the slide every 2 seconds (in this case).

In function `changeSlide` first you need to get total slides and the width of the first one (because all have the same width).

Then if it's the last slide set `margin-left` to 0 and if it's not then subtract the photo `width` of the current `margin-left` in the state. At the end update the state.

Hope that this will give you the idea how you can do it.

[Here is the fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/1758/)